# photogrammetry with partially translucent objects

Tags: 3d-models

I've captured a stationary spinning object in a computer game. It's semi translucent and there are stationary objects behind it.

As I expected it did not convert using Autodesk's remake. It gives no explanation other than 'Error'. I obviously can't paint the object. Are there any techniques in Photoshop that will let me manually fix the images to reduce the translucency?

Any other program that might produce a mesh from images? The game objects can't be extracted via any other program I've tried.

Comment: Did you mean to post this in 3d printing?

Comment: The intent is to 3d print the result. I'm not sure anyone without 3d scanning/printing experience would understand what I need to do.

Comment: Hi, @Jay! You question does fall somewhere in between several sites here on Stack Exchange. Do you think Photography or Robotics perhaps could give more feedback?

Comment: Regarding your actual question: is it so that you have several individual photos captured from a spinning game object? If so, could something like [photomodeler](http://www.photomodeler.com/products/modeler/default.html) perhaps do the trick?

Comment: I captured a video stream of a floating spinning crystal. I was then able to extract and crop individual frames. The autodesk online site is unable to work with translucent or shiny objects. Unfortunately this is both so it failed. I suspect photomodeller will have the same limitations but thanks for the link. I'll try it

Comment: I downloaded the [photoshop cs5](http://fileparrots.blogspot.com/2017/08/download-adobe-photoshop-cs5-free.html) and work in it.

Answer (score 4):

I found at least 2 online pages that'll create a 3D stl from an image, basically using intensity (brightness) to determine depth.

[selva3d.com](http://www.selva3d.com/)  and   [embossify.com](http://www.embossify.com/)

I used it with success on a binary (black or white) image, at least.

Comment: Nice links, but this object is fully 3d. It's a crystal that floats in the air. The blue thingy in this picture: http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/asheron/images/4/42/Lifestone_Live.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141117092544